# Automating performance tests in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-10, benchmark

I want to check the performance of specific queries in a Postgres database on a regular basis. Also, I want to be able to check the change in performance of different queries with any change in my Postgres configuration or database schema/indexes.

So far I have tried `pgbench`, but feel like I need to automate the process of passing the script `pgbench` will use to test. But `pgbench` tests my configuration by generating its own tables and those tables will not reflect the level of joins I might be using on real data.

I'm using Postgres 10.0

Comment: You can supply your own SQL scripts to pgbench (table creation and queries)

Comment: Not a concrete answer but a pointer in a possible direction: Robot Framework (RF) https://robotframework.org/ + http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/ (use the psycopg2 db adapter to set it up) and optionally + https://github.com/damies13/rfswarm. Since pgbench is a cli tool it can be triggert from RF with it's buildin process-library.